# Is it possible to fetch the AST data from a compiler?

Tags: c#, abstract-syntax-tree

So I have challenged myself with a task to write a program that can list all the methods and variables from a given cs file. I did some research and came across Abstract Syntax Tree stuff, so I was wondering if I can somehow use that to achieve my goal? Is it possible to do so? How? Or is there any other better way to do what I want?

Comment: Depends on the goal of your assignment. If the intent is that you write a parser for C#, the syntax tree won't help you, because that already skips that part. On the other hand, getting all the methods and its parameters from a cs class is easy, just use the `Type.GetMethods()` reflection method. Or even easier, use `ildasm`.

Comment: welp that was easier than expected, but what if I wanna know which variables are local to which function and so?

Comment: Gets a little bit trickier, but still doable: The `MethodInfo` instances you get from the `GetMethods()` call has a `GetMethodBody()` method. And that result contains a `LocalVariables` property.